# Is there a way to get C++ destructors called eagerly?

Tags: c++, optimization, scope, destructor

Some of the functions in my C++ code have temporary local objects that use a lot of heap memory. So I'd like them to be destructed and release their memory as soon as I'm done with them. But C++ only calls the destructor when the variable name goes out of scope. Is there a way to let the compiler automatically call the destructor or another cleanup method at the end of the variable's liveness range instead?

Of course I could just new/delete the objects manually, but that's inconvenient and bug prone. Equally unsatisfactory is the use of extra braces to limit the scope explicitly.

EDIT: Judging by the responses it seems like this can't be done with current C++ features. I'll suggest it for the next standard.

Comment: what do you mean with "liveness range" ? Are you maybe looking for smart pointers?

Comment: Very much sounds like your functions are way too long.

Comment: How about using a `clear` method, which can be called manually but will also be called by the destructor?

Comment: How about smart pointers, more specifically [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)? Then you can [release](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release) the contained object at any time. Or as a commenter above hinted, use shorter functions?

Comment: @tobi303, but inside smart pointers it uses dynamic allocation.

Comment: "Equally unsatisfactory is the use of extra braces to limit the scope explicitly". Learn to love that technique.

Comment: also I dont understand the last part of using new/delete vs use of extra braces. Thats not alternatives, because either the object is allocated on the heap, then you have to use new/delete and adding braces wont help at all. Or it is on the stack then it is the other way around...

Comment: @dhke Functions being too long is one assumption.. but short functions can also be pretty long-*running* without being very much code.

Comment: @tobi303 - I suspect the OP means something like `vector<int> x(100000000000000000);`.

Comment: RAII will help you. or you can make a global manager, which would clean objects that are not used for a long time.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I suspect the OP is giving too little information :P

Comment: @fgrdn RAII won't help and a "global manager, which would clean objects that are not used for a long time" sounds like a pretty bad idea in general.

Comment: @SimonKraemer tell A so tell B

Comment: Have you thought about extracting parts of the functions into smaller functions that will delete the objects when leaving the scope?

Comment: @nhgrif The part about nested blocks already lets 200 line function bodies with lots of intermediate variable declarations scroll past my internal screen.

Comment: @fgrdn What are you trying to say?

Comment: Destructors are already as "eager" as they can be. Sounds like you're just writing bad code. Why not post it on Code Review?

Comment: I don't know what is your use case, but maybe you can [clear & minimize](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Clear-and-minimize) you objects?

Comment: @SimonKraemer you just told "no", but not specify why not. RAII obvious helps with such problems. global manager (let's say - some sort of classic resources manager which manages cahced objects) also can be used. of course it depends.

Comment: @fgrdn: RAII requires the "extra braces" (that the OP wishes to avoid) to be useful.

Comment: @fgrdn: 1) OP already uses objects that are destroyed when leaving the scope. RAII does exactly this for non-object ressources - so it doesn't make sense to reapply RAII on the OPs code.

Comment: @fgrdn: 2) A manager as you "described" it makes sense when you plan to keep the data in memory for a longer and not for a shorter period. Plus it can introduce additional errors and the data is moved from stack to heap and ....

Comment: @tobi303 Liveness analysis is a compilation pass which determines at which point a variable is no longer needed. It's an important part of register allocation, to know when a register can be used by another variable even before it goes out of scope. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_variable_analysis

Since the compiler already has liveness information, it could use this to eagerly call the destructor.

Comment: @dhke The functions are not necessarily very long. This is for an EDSL to construct data processing pipelines, similar to Halide: http://halide-lang.org/. There can be large temporary objects that are only used for a couple of stages in the pipeline. It would be inconvenient, bug prone and ugly to have to manually release them or limit their scope.

Comment: @NicolasCapens "length" is quite relative. But if you have a subsequence of operations that is creating a data object that is no longer needed after the subsequence completes, you have also found a natural location for introducing an abstraction, hence a subfunction.

Comment: @SimonKraemer This is for the EDSL of a framework library, so I don't have direct control over how people use it. Splitting things into separate functions where reasonable is suggested, but there are undoubtedly cases where that leads to less readable code. I don't want the users of my library to have to worry about implementation details and require manual deleting of temporary buffers. It's starting to sound like C++ doesn't offer the desired functionality though. :(

Comment: @dhke Compilers perform liveness analysis precisely because it is extremely common for variables to no longer be live before the end of their scope, including for functions that are not excessively long. It would be a big burden to require programmers to split each scope into a subfunction. But while the compiler solved this problem for us for the case of register allocation, it does not seem to help us out for resources allocated by objects, by calling the destructor early. I was just hoping there was another language feature or trick that could accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @NicolasCapens You are probably forgetting that C++ only *seems* to be a high level language ;-). Variables are valid within their scope, there is no "magic" way to invalidate them halfway down the line. If the compiler produced code that did so, it would violate the standard. Liveness analysis for register allocation is quite a different beast, however. Every good C++ compiler will do that, but it cannot change the language's data model. Your big variable might not have an assigned register at the end of your function, but he memory is still there, because it has to be.

Comment: @dhke Why? What's the point of not destructing an object after its last use? And before you answer that, I do know of two practical use cases: scoped mutex locks, and tracing the entry and exit of functions. But that doesn't seem like it would have been used as an argument when the spec was written. My suspicion is that destruction was decided to be based on scope because it made compiler implementation easier in the early days. That's hardly a concern now, and releasing resources sooner would be a valuable feature.

Comment: @NicolasCapens you idea will also violate another rule - objects destroyed in reverse order of creation. There can be many situations this is harmful. First of all because behavior is not predictable.

Comment: Without some sample code, this question is not specific enough for Stack Overflow.  I'm voting to close as *too broad*.

Comment: @Slava In situations where you rely on the destruction order to be the reverse of the creation order, you just wouldn't use this feature. I don't think this is any worse than the risks involved in manual destruction. C++ already demands you to be aware of the lifetime paradigm that's in use for each situation. A well designed framework would make it intuitive or even foolproof. I don't see why you think its behavior would not be predictable.

Comment: @NicolasCapens unfortunately C++ is already way too overcomplicated, creating this will make it even worse (if that is possible). I doubt benefit would worse the effort. You can create proper scope already (what you should do to produce good quality code anyway) or release resources manually.

Comment: @TobySpeight "too broad" means there are too many valid answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions That's clearly not the case here, as it looks like this isn't currently supported by C++. Sample code wouldn't clarify the question (for anyone proficient in C++), and probably detract from the real issue.

Comment: @Nicolas, I disagree.  If you have a non-const `std::string`, it's quite easy to assign an empty string to it.  That said, I don't understand the opposition to using the scope mechanism we're given (using braces) which is clear, unambiguous and well-understood.

Comment: @Slava I beg to differ. This would make C++ easier to use by eliminating the need to manually release the resources or place distracting braces. Also note that C++ is a multi-paradigm language where you just use what you need. Nobody's forcing you to use it, and if it's used by a framework you have a use for, it's probably going to make things easier for you than complicate things.

Comment: @NicolasCapens I doubt it would make it easier to use. First - situation when you have an object which holds so much resources is very seldom. Second and more important - you should keep variables in smallest possible scopes. So that will make writing bad code easier, I doubt it is a good reason.

Comment: @TobySpeight Adding braces is not desired for the same reason nobody would want to use them to indicate live ranges of scalar variables. Sure, doing it for one object or explicitly releasing its resources would be easy, but it becomes unmanageable to do it for all of them. That's why we rely on the compiler to do liveness analysis. But it doesn't work for resources released in the destructor. I think that's a real optimization concern, and could be solved with a new language feature.

Comment: *"I'll suggest it for the next standard."* - How do you propose that a compiler deduce, that you are done with an object? What if an object lives for the sole reason of having its [d'tor invoked, at a deterministic time](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040520-00/?p=39243/)? This feature isn't going to make it into the standard. And why should it? We already have the tool you are asking for: Scoping manages the livetime of objects with automatic storage duration. Use it!

Answer (score 5):

You may use inner scope, but it is generally sign that you might use sub function

```
void foo()
{

    // some stuff
    {
        BigData bigData;

        // some other stuff
    } // bigData is released now.

    // some other stuff
}
```

That doesn't handle interleaving variables.

Comment: "Equally unsatisfactory is the use of extra braces to limit the scope explicitly." OP doesn't wan't braces (but they'll likely have to deal with them :-) )

Comment: @AndyG: Even more equally unsatisfactory are pointless constraints made up by the OP for no reason.

Comment: @KerreSB agree, but "more equally" just sounds too funny ;)

Comment: @KerrekSB It's not a pointless constraint. Compilers perform liveness analysis for register allocation purposes because programmers clearly don't want the constraint of having to indicate variable liveness manually via scope. So why would it be unreasonable to extend that from registers (and stack memory), to heap memory, by automatically calling the destructor at the end of a local object's live range?

Comment: @NicolasCapens: Think about `lock_guard` variable which is .. not used explicitly after its definition, but should remain until end of scope.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, cases like that can continue to use the current behavior of destruction at end of scope. I was just looking for a way to optionally instruct the compiler to call the destructor sooner.

Answer (score 1):

No, a destructor, by definition, gets invoked only as part of the object's destruction sequence.

However, nothing stops you from releasing and deallocating any resources your class has without waiting for a destructor.

For example, if your class has a large `std::list` class member, there's no law that prohibits you from invoking `clear()`, to remove its contents, without waiting for that to happen naturally in the destructor.

Or, if your class destructor is "safe", and does what needs to be done, simply factor it out into a private class method, leaving the destructor to contain nothing but the private method call, and do the same whenever you want to free the same resources.

Answer (score 1):

If the effort is really worth it (measure at least twice!), you could use [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to enable you to destruct selected class-types sooner.

Be sure you cannot achieve your aim using scoping though.

Comment: How would it automatically destruct the object on last use?

Comment: @NicolasCapens: There is no way to automatically destroy it on last use, especially as the objects existence might be the important thing (consider locking or signalling program state for example). It's just the closest thing possible, in allowing you to create/destroy earlier and making sure the lifetime is still managed properly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to control the lifetime of an object is to use `std::optional`. This will allow for the object to end its lifetime early, but the process is not automatic. It will require manually setting the variable to `nullopt`

To get the automatic behaviour you would like you could define a type alias for `std::optional`

```
template <typename T>
using eagerly_destroy = optional<T>;
```

Next you will need to create a program that process your source code to find all variables declared with this eagery_destroy template and find the last use of those variables and add the `= nullopt` to the right places.

Or you could find an open source compiler implementation and use that as a starting point to implement the feature you are suggesting.